# Trouble initializing NSViewController - UI Objects not retained

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm having some issues with understanding how to work with NSViewControllers on Mac. I'm trying to create custom table cells for NSTableView. In one of the delegates of the NSTableView, it can return a view, instead of a cell.

I have a subclass of NSViewController, and in the .xib everything is linked up correctly, but when I initialize the NSViewController, its UI components is not initialized... not even the default view that comes with it. I have tried it with a clean, stock, untouched implementation of NSViewController, just to make sure that the issue is not with something I'm doing. It is probably. I am initializing the NSViewController as follows:

```
testview *tmpChannel = [[testview alloc] initWithNibName:@"testview" bundle:nil];
```

The .xib does exist, and all the outlets are linked up correctly. Could anyone explain what is happening here? I'm using xCode 4.1 with Lion OS

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have managed to get it running using the following code:

`if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"ChannelViewController" owner:tmpChannel])
    {
        NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load myNib file.\n");

    }`

Can anyone explain why the xib is linked and loaded initially?

Comment: Edit:
Can anyone explain why the xib is *not* linked and loaded initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your initialization with

```
NSLog(@"%@", [tmpChannel description]);
```

From your code I would assume, that you do get an object address here. That means the error is probably in the code that is supposed to display it.

BTW, I recommend using capitalized class names, such as `TestView`.

**EDIT:**

Additional Information for loading xibs: The name of the xib file has to be the **exact same** as the class name. In this case you can actually completely omit the `initWithNibName:bundle:` part:

```
// xib file is "ViewController.xib"
// Class is defined as "ViewController"

ViewController *newController = [[ViewController alloc] init];  // this is enough
```

Comment: Hi there, the output I received was the object's class and memory address (<testview: 0x102b4bfa0>). As for the nasty class name, I was in a bit of a hurry when I created the class...

Comment: Please also check your "UI components" that are "not initialized". Which components? How do you check?

Comment: Ok, I have managed to get it running using the following code: `if (![NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"ChannelViewController" owner:tmpChannel]) { NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load myNib file.\n"); }` Can anyone explain why the xib is linked and loaded initially?

Comment: Edit:
Can anyone explain why the xib is *not* linked and loaded initially?

Answer (score 0):

The IB (xib) Objects are initialized only after the view is actually loaded. And not during the initWithNibName:bundle: